# How to make a (photorealistic) material similar to tomato placenta and inner circle similar to this?

Tags: materials, node-editor, normals, color, displacement

I'm trying to create a completely synthetic tomato slice, any suggestions on how do I achieve it to look more similar to a real tomato slice via only nodes setup? I’m trying to get a more realistic render. I feel that my biggest issue is my lighting and then my materials. However i’m not quite sure how to go about improving both.

synth:[image]
real:[image]

Comment: No textures at all?

Comment: @RobinBetts yep

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm, as far as I understand,

1. the real thing does not have a solid 1/0 boundary between the liquid and the solid part
2. all surfaces have a lot of microbumps.

So what I can think of here is that you can try taking two different levels of noise textures, and using the one with larger scale value for the solid part and the one with the smaller scale for the gooey/liquid part of the tomato.

Also, try blending in the borders between the two, make it so that the boundary of hard part is more like a slope like the ocean shore rather than a straight-up vertical fall like the well.

And yeah, that's really it, the shine added by the correct displacement map would do most of the heavy lifting. Ofcourse you can do this manually with a fractal subdivision if you want.